# Non Empty Set Dense In The Topological Subspace

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $A$ is a non empty subset of a topological space $(X, T)$, then prove that $A$ is a dense subset of the subspace $\overline{A}$.
$$$$Please Check My Proof
$$$$Now as a subspace of a given topological space is formed by the relative topology. Now the subspace is the topological space $(\overline{A}, T')$ with the topology $T'$ which is the collection of sets formed by the intersection of the class of sets in $T$ with $\overline{A}$. Now any subset of $\overline{A}$ open under $T$ lies in $T$ and hence lies in $T'$. Also any subset of $\overline{A}$ open under $T'$ lies in $T'$ and hence lies in $T$. Hence any subset of $\overline{A}$ is open under $T$ if and only if it is open under $T'$. Now to prove the above statement we need to show that the closure of $A$ under $T'$ say $\overline{A'}$ is equal to closure of $A$ under $T$, that is $$\overline{A'}=\overline{A}$$. Now any superset of $A$ lying in $\overline{A}$ which is closed under $T'$ is also closed under $T$ and by the definition of $\overline{A}$ we see that $\overline{A}$ lies in that set and hence $\overline{A}$ is equal to that set. So the only superset of $A$ closed under $T'$ lying in $\overline{A}$ is itself $\overline{A}$ and hence $$\overline{A'}=\overline{A}$$. So we get that $$\overline{A'}=\overline{A}$$ which proves that $A$ is dense in the topological subspace $(\overline{A}, T')$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U\in T'$ with $U\cap A=\varnothing$.

Then $U=V\cap\overline A$ for some $V\in T$ so that $U\cap A=\varnothing$ implies that $V\cap A=\varnothing$ or equivalently that $A\subseteq V^{\complement}$.

Because $V^{\complement}$ is closed it follows that $\overline A\subseteq V^{\complement}$ or equivalently $U=\varnothing$ .

Proved is now that: $$\forall U\in T'[U\cap A=\varnothing\implies U=\varnothing]$$

We can reformulate this as: $$\forall U\in T'[U\neq\varnothing\implies U\cap A\neq\varnothing]$$

This is exactly the statement that $A$ is dense in space $(\overline A,T')$.

Comment: Is my proof Correct??

Comment: You are saying that any subset of $\bar A$ open under $T'$ also lies in $T$. That sounds wrong. For instance $\bar A$ itself is an element of $T'$ but not necessarily of $T$. In that sense is does not necessarily "lies in $T$".

Comment: But how can you say that $\overline{A}$ lies in $T'$

Comment: Because $\bar A=X\cap\bar A$ and $X\in T$. That is how $T'$ is defined. Intersections of $\bar A$ with elements of $T$.